# MSSQL Query framing

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables like master and 2 child tables . I am using join condition but did not get as expected client needs.

[image]

Query:

```
select * from(
select a.id as mid,b.id,b.val from ##mastertable a right join ##table1 b 
on a.id=b.id ) as c inner join ##table2 d on c.mid=d.id
```

Kindly provide any other way to get proper result.

Comment: can you please provide sample data and expected output in table sstructure

Comment: I have added sample tables in image format .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select a.id, b.id, b.val
From (mastertable a
Right Join table1 b 
On a.id = b.id)
Inner Join table2 d
On a.id = d.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting . But expected result not came.

Answer (score 0):

Try below: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b58625961c444997829abb45d40417b

```
select * from master m inner join
(select table2.id as id1, table2.value as val1, table1.value as val2, table1.id as id2
from table2 left join table1 
on table1.id=table2.id and  table1.value=table2.value)x on m.id=x.id1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
select * from (
(select master.id from master_table) master
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(select table1.id, table1.value from table_1) table1
ON
master.id = table1.id
FULL OUTER JOIN
(select table2.id, table2.value from table_2) table2
ON
table1.id = table2.id
AND
table1.val = table2.val
)
;
```

Comment: actually values are different don't join values column .

Answer (score 0):

This will be same as you expected

```
select 
m.id, t1.id, t1.value, t2.id, t2.value
from
m
left join
t1
on
m.id = t1.id
left join
t2
on
t1.id = t2.id and t1.value = t2.value
order by m.id, t1.value
```

here M is your master table, T1 is table1 and t2 is table2